# Android, не меняется Drawable в EditText после вызова setError

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Имеется вот такое поле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию установлена иконка с серым конвертом. На поле навешен `onTextChanged`, меняющий иконку когда вводимый email становится валидным. Если значение валидное, `onTextChanged` меняет иконку и внешний флаг `isEmailCorrect`. Если не валидное - возвращает серую иконку. Когда `isEmailCorrect`  становится в true, пользователь может по кнопке запустить поверку `validationSuccess()`, которая в случае провала вызовет у поля `setError()` с третьей картинкой.

Проблема в том что если пользователь завалит проверку, то иконка поля перестанет меняться при удачной валидации, будто бы `onTextChanged` перестал работать.

Если короче: после `validationSuccess()` иконка поля не меняется при пользовательском вводе. Прошу помочь.

---

**UPD**: вводя валидный email после выполнения `validationSuccess()`, код в ветке if в `onTextChanged` выполняется. То есть значение проходит проверку корректно. Такое ощущение, словно после `validationSuccess()` перестаёт работать это:

```
binding.textAuthorizationEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_email_correct, 0);
```

---

Поле:

```
binding.textAuthorizationEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (binding.textAuthorizationEmail.getText().length() != 0
                && Utility.isValidEmail(String.valueOf(binding.textAuthorizationEmail.getText()))) {


 binding.textAuthorizationEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_email_correct, 0);
                isEmailCorrect = true;
            } else {
                binding.textAuthorizationEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_email, 0);
                binding.buttonAuthorizationSend.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                isEmailCorrect = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

**validationSuccess()**

```
 public boolean validationSuccess() {
            boolean isSuccess = true;
            if (binding.textAuthorizationEmail.getText().length() == 0) {
                binding.textAuthorizationEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_validation_empty), getErrorIcon(this, R.drawable.ic_email_error));
                isEmailCorrect = false;
                isSuccess = false;
            } else if (!Utility.isValidEmail(String.valueOf(binding.textAuthorizationEmail.getText()))) {
                binding.textAuthorizationEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_validation_email), getErrorIcon(this, R.drawable.ic_email_error));
                isEmailCorrect = false;
                isSuccess = false;
            }
       return isSuccess;
        }
```

**Xml:**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_authorization_email_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_ultra_big"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:hint="@string/hint_email"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

      <EditText
         android:id="@+id/text_authorization_email"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_email"
         android:gravity="start"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**@style/TextLabel**

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/color_grey</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Пробовали при изменении текста сделать .setError(null) ? Фактически когда пользователь начинает редактировать e-mail то ошибку надо сбрасывать.

Comment: Попробовал(во всех переопределенных методах), к успеху не привело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам посредством:

`binding.textAuthorizationEmail.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,null,null);`

в `onTextChanged`.

Не спрашивайте меня как это решает проблему, я без понятия.=)